# In Swift, an efficient function that separates an array into 2 arrays based on a predicate

Tags: arrays, swift

#### Note: I'm currently still using Swift 2.2, but open to Swift 3 solutions as well

I'm looking to create a function that operates very closely to `filter`, except that it keeps the non-matching results as well, and maintains sort order. For instance, say you wanted to filter out numbers divisible by 3 in an array and still keep the list of numbers that aren't divisible by 3.

---

#### Option 1: Using `filter`

With `filter`, you only get the list of numbers divisible by 3 and the original list stays unchanged. You can then filter the original list again with the opposite predicate, but this is an unnecessary second pass. The code looks like this:

```
let numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
let divisibleBy3 = numbers.filter { $0 % 3 == 0 } // [3,6,9]
let theRest = numbers.filter { $0 % 3 != 0 }      // [1,2,4,5,7,8,10]
```

It's true that this is pretty readable, but the fact that it does 2 passes seems inefficient to me, especially if the predicate were more complicated. That's twice as many checks as are actually needed.

#### Option 2: Using custom `separate` function in `Collection` extension

My next attempt was extending `Collection` and making a function I called `separate`. This function would take the collection and go through the elements one at a time and add them to either the matching list or the non-matching list. The code looks like this:

```
extension Collection {
    func separate(predicate: (Generator.Element) -> Bool) -> (matching: [Generator.Element], notMatching: [Generator.Element]) {
        var groups: ([Generator.Element],[Generator.Element]) = ([],[])
        for element in self {
            if predicate(element) {
                groups.0.append(element)
            } else {
                groups.1.append(element)
            }
        }
        return groups
    }
}
```

I can then use the function like this:

```
let numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
let groups = numbers.separate { $0 % 3 == 0 }
let matching = groups.matching       // [3,6,9]
let notMatching = groups.notMatching // [1,2,4,5,7,8,10]
```

This is also pretty clean, but the only thing I don't like is that I'm using a tuple as a return type. Maybe others will disagree, but I'd prefer returning the same type as `self` for chaining. But technically, you can just grab either `.matching` or `.notMatching`, which is the same type as `self`, and you can chain off of either of them.

#### Option 3: Using a custom, mutating `removeIf` function in `Array` extension

My issue with `separate` returning a tuple led me to try to make a function that would modify `self` by removing the matches as it found them and adding them to a new list, and returning the matches list at the end. The returned list is your matches, and the array is trimmed of those values. Order is preserved in both arrays. The code looks like this:

```
extension Array {
    mutating func removeIf(predicate: (Element) -> Bool) -> [Element] {
        var removedCount: Int = 0
        var removed: [Element] = []

        for (index,element) in self.enumerated() {
            if predicate(element) {
                removed.append(self.remove(at: index-removedCount))
                removedCount += 1
            }
        }

        return removed
    }
}
```

And it is used like this:

```
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
let divisibleBy3 = numbers.removeIf { $0 % 3 == 0 }
// divisibleBy3: [3,6,9]
// numbers:      [1,2,4,5,7,8,10]
```

This function had to be implemented in an extension of `Array`, because the concept of removing an element at a particular index doesn't apply to regular `Collections` (an `Array` is defined as `public struct Array<Element> : RandomAccessCollection, MutableCollection`, and it directly defines the `remove(at:)` function, rather than getting it from inheritance or a protocol).

#### Option 4: Combination of Option 2 and 3

I'm a big fan of code reuse, and after coming up with Option 3, I realized I could probably reuse the `separate` function from Option 2. I came up with this:

```
extension Array {
    mutating func removeIf(predicate: (Element) -> Bool) -> [Element] {
        let groups = self.separate(predicate: predicate)
        self = groups.notMatching
        return groups.matching
    }
}
```

And it's used just like in Option 3.

I was concerned with performance, so I ran each Option through XCTest's `measure` with 1000 iterations. These were the results:

```
Option 1: 9 ms
Option 2: 7 ms
Option 3: 10 ms
Option 4: 8 ms
```

---

#### Option 5: Based on negaipro's answer

I knew about `partition`, but I wasn't going to consider it because it didn't preserve the sort order. negaipro's answer is essentially `partition`, but it got me thinking. The idea with `partition` is to swap elements that match with the pivot point, thus ensuring that everything on one side of the end pivot point will all match the predicate and the other side doesn't. I took that idea and changed the action to "move to the end". So matches are removed from their spot and added to the end.

```
extension Array {
    mutating func swapIfModified(predicate: (Element) -> Bool) -> Int {
        var matchCount = 0
        var index = 0
        while index < (count-matchCount) {
            if predicate(self[index]) {
                append(remove(at: index))
                matchCount += 1
            } else {
                index += 1
            }
        }

        return count-matchCount
    }
}
```

Under my initial tests using an array with 10 numbers, it was comparable to the other Options. But I was concerned with the performance of the line `append(remove(at: index))`. So I tried all the Options again with arrays going from 1 to 1000, and this option was definitely the slowest.

---

#### Conclusion:

There isn't a big performance difference between these options. And since Option 4 was faster than Option 3 and reuses the code from Option 2, I'm inclined to throw out Option 3. So I'm leaning towards using plain old `filter` when I don't care about the unfiltered results (and, likewise, for when I don't care about the filtered results, since it's just using the opposite predicate), and then using either `separate` or `removeIf` when I care about keeping both the filtered and unfiltered results.

#### Question:

So, am I missing something built into Swift that does this already? Is there a better way to accomplish this? Is my extension syntax missing anything (anything that could make it apply this concept to more areas, for example)?

Comment: reduce!!!!!! :D

Comment: Please explain further. How is reduce what I'm looking for? I need 2 arrays. Reduce produces a single element.

Comment: What if your single element was an array of two arrays

Comment: That's not much better than a 2-tuple, in my opinion. Actually, I think it's worse, since a 2-tuple is guaranteed to have only 2 values, but an array of arrays could have any number of arrays inside it.

Comment: In that case, a tuple would be better then, so what if your single element was a tuple of `([Int], [Int])`?

Comment: At this point you are referring to what I outlined in Option 2, except using generic types instead of `Int`.

Comment: I have posted an answer, see if it helps

Comment: Isn't this a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @HAS Well it's only a code review if there isn't some built-in that I don't know about. See the first question in my last paragraph: "am I missing something built into Swift that does this already?"

Comment: @Tim I still think it's for code review because you have working code, you don't have a particular problem to solve.

Comment: I still say it's not a code review if someone comes along and says "forget all that stuff. What you want is this built-in function, `foo`. It does exactly what you're looking for and it's faster than your other solutions." People post code with their questions all the time and say "Is there a better way?". In fact, negaipro's answer below has me thinking of a better solution already.

Comment: `remove(at:)` is part of `RangeReplaceableCollection`, FWIW.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Technically, this is not guaranteed to preserve order, but it does.

```swift
Dictionary(grouping: numbers) { $0.isMultiple(of: 3) }
```

https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/NativeDictionary.swift

Comment: I like this. I'll be curious to find example where the order isn't preserved. It's certainly a very compact solution. I'll have to performance test it as well.

Comment: I did some benchmarking, and the custom `separate` function from my Option 2 was slightly more performant, but not by much. I couldn't find any documentation that would say that the "grouping" init wouldn't guarantee preserving order, but from looking at the source, it looks like it would. It's just adding the matching entries, in order, to one of 2 buckets. It's a nice initializer to know.

Comment: I think this is the closest I'm going to get to succinctly answering "So, am I missing something built into Swift that does this already?", so I'm marking it as the answer. I want others to know the glory of the grouping initializer.

Comment: This is a great solution (+1), but the link to the Dictionary class is (for me) not very helpful. A few words of explanation would have helped me more.

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 4 Solution**

[partition(by:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017524-partition#declarations)

It reorders the origin array and returns start index of subarray satisfies the predicate.

In this example it returns 7.

0..<7 elemets aren't divisible by 3 and 7..n-1 elements are divisible by 3.

```
 var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
 let partition = numbers.partition(by: { $0 % 3 == 0 })
 let divisibleBy3 = Array(numbers[..<partition]) //[3,6,9]
 let theRest = Array(numbers[partition...]) //[1,2,4,5,7,8,10]
```

Comment: `partition`, as I have stated before, doesn't preserve ordering, and therefore does not meet the initial requirements.

Answer (score 6):

```
let objects: [Int] = Array(1..<11)
let split = objects.reduce(([Int](), [Int]())) { (value, object) -> ([Int], [Int]) in

    var value = value

    if object % 2 == 0 {
        value.1.append(object)
    } else {
        value.0.append(object)
    }

    return value
}
```

Comment: How is this really any different than what I posed in Option 2?

Comment: Well it uses the reduce function instead, they are both O(n) but it's just another way to do it

Comment: O(n) is pretty much as good as you're going to get unless you know the elements are sorted in a particular way before hand

Comment: This actually runs in quadratic, not linear time as `value` will be copied at each iteration – see [Airspeed Velocity's blog post on the subject](https://airspeedvelocity.net/2015/08/03/arrays-linked-lists-and-performance/).

Comment: O(n) isn't a problem. The main point of my question is to see if there was already some built in function that did this. If there isn't, then I want to know if there's something much faster or cleaner than my proposed solutions.

Comment: @TimFuqua okay I see, I'll be interested to see what the best solution is

Comment: This solution is less efficient than @RajeshKumar R's

Answer (score 5):

There is a new [Swift Algorithms open-source](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms) for sequence and collection algorithms, along with their related types.

You can use the stable partition from there

Methods for performing a stable partition on mutable collections, and for
finding the partitioning index in an already partitioned collection.

The standard library’s existing `partition(by:)` method, which re-orders the
elements in a collection into two partitions based on a given predicate, doesn’t
guarantee stability for either partition. That is, the order of the elements in
each partition doesn’t necessarily match their relative order in the original
collection. These new methods expand on the existing `partition(by:)` by
providing stability for one or both partitions.

```swift
// existing partition(by:) - unstable ordering
var numbers = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80]
let p1 = numbers.partition(by: { $0.isMultiple(of: 20) })
// p1 == 4
// numbers == [10, 70, 30, 50, 40, 60, 20, 80]

// new stablePartition(by:) - keeps the relative order of both partitions
numbers = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80]
let p2 = numbers.stablePartition(by: { $0.isMultiple(of: 20) })
// p2 == 4
// numbers == [10, 30, 50, 70, 20, 40, 60, 80]
```

Since partitioning is frequently used in divide-and-conquer algorithms, we also
include a variant that accepts a range parameter to avoid copying when mutating
slices, as well as a range-based variant of the existing standard library
partition.

The  `partitioningIndex(where:)` method returns the index of the start of the
second partition when called on an already partitioned collection.

```swift
let numbers = [10, 30, 50, 70, 20, 40, 60]
let p = numbers.partitioningIndex(where: { $0.isMultiple(of: 20) })
// numbers[..<p] == [10, 30, 50, 70]
// numbers[p...] = [20, 40, 60]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
// swap and return pivot
extension Array
{
    // return pivot
    mutating func swapIf(predicate: (Element) -> Bool) -> Int
    {
        var pivot = 0
        for i in 0..<self.count
        {
            if predicate( self[i] )
            {
                if i > 0
                {
                    swap(&self[i], &self[pivot])
                }

                pivot += 1
            }
        }

        return pivot
    }
}
```

This is my code and the concept is.. reduce memory usage.

I checked that 'swapIf' is 4-times faster than 'removeIf'.

Comment: Close. What you've created is actually already part of the Swift Standard Library. It's called `partition` (https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/2294611-partition). And while it is fast, it doesn't preserve order, which is part of why it's so fast. And since my elements aren't guaranteed to be in a particular sort order, I can't just sort the 2 resulting arrays afterwards either. But you've given me an idea for a possibly faster solution.

Comment: See my updated answer. A solution that would preserve the ordering is still slower than Options 2 and 4. But if you didn't care about the ordering, your solution (or `partition`) would certainly be the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

## Solution A

For fewer elements this may be fastest.

```
extension Array {
    func stablePartition(by condition: (Element) -> Bool) -> ([Element], [Element]) {
        var matching = [Element]()
        var nonMatching = [Element]()
        for element in self {
            if condition(element) {
                matching.append(element)
            } else {
                nonMatching.append(element)
            }
        }
        return (matching, nonMatching)
    }
}
```

#### Usage

```
let numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
let (divisibleBy3, theRest) = numbers.stablePartition { $0 % 3 == 0 }
print("divisible by 3: \(divisibleBy3), the rest: \(theRest)")
// divisible by 3: [3, 6, 9], the rest: [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10]
```

---

## Solution B

For many elements this may be faster, because of fewer allocations. I have not measured performance.

```
extension Array {
    public func stablePartition(by condition: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> ([Element], [Element]) {
        var indexes = Set<Int>()
        for (index, element) in self.enumerated() {
            if try condition(element) {
                indexes.insert(index)
            }
        }
        var matching = [Element]()
        matching.reserveCapacity(indexes.count)
        var nonMatching = [Element]()
        nonMatching.reserveCapacity(self.count - indexes.count)
        for (index, element) in self.enumerated() {
            if indexes.contains(index) {
                matching.append(element)
            } else {
                nonMatching.append(element)
            }
        }
        return (matching, nonMatching)
    }
}
```

Comment: It's O(n) and I doubt you can get more efficient than that.

Comment: Array has a `reserveCapacity()` that can lower the number of allocations and maybe improve performance.

Comment: This is essentially Option 2 from my original post, just specific to Arrays instead of Collections. And I showed how Option 4 uses a combination of Option 2 and Option 3 to perform specifically for Arrays. So this solution isn't really any different from options already presented.

Comment: @TimFuqua I have just now added another solution, so there is now A + B. I originally wrote solution B. Next morning I removed the Set code and ended up with solution A, which very similar to your Option 2 code. Pure coincidence :-)   Do you think `Collection` is better than `Array` ?

Comment: You'll notice that my Option 2 is an extension on Collection. This is because you can iterate over any Collection. Option 3, and subsequently Option 4 which is a combination of Option 2 and Option 3, is specifically an extension on Array because it needs to modify the group of elements by index lookup, which you can't do on every Collection, but you can on an Array.

Comment: You are right. It's better to extend the `Collection` protocol

Answer (score 2):

In WWDC 2018 session [Embracing Algorithm](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/223/) they mention the function `stablePartition`, you can take a look here https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/test/Prototypes/Algorithms.swift

```
extension Collection where Self : MutableCollectionAlgorithms {

  @discardableResult
  mutating func stablePartition(
    isSuffixElement: (Element) throws -> Bool
  ) rethrows -> Index {
        return try stablePartition(
            count: count, isSuffixElement: isSuffixElement)
  }

    /// Moves all elements satisfying `isSuffixElement` into a suffix of the collection,
    /// preserving their relative order, returning the start of the resulting suffix.
    ///
    /// - Complexity: O(n) where n is the number of elements.
    /// - Precondition: `n == self.count`
    fileprivate mutating func stablePartition(
        count n: Int, isSuffixElement: (Element) throws-> Bool
    ) rethrows -> Index {
        if n == 0 { return startIndex }
        if n == 1 {
            return try isSuffixElement(self[startIndex]) ? startIndex : endIndex
        }
        let h = n / 2, i = index(startIndex, offsetBy: h)
        let j = try self[..<i].stablePartition(
            count: h, isSuffixElement: isSuffixElement)
        let k = try self[i...].stablePartition(
            count: n - h, isSuffixElement: isSuffixElement)
        return self[j..<k].rotate(shiftingToStart: i)
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't present in standard lib of Swift 4.2 in Xcode10, or i missing something?

Comment: My original question was written with Swift 2 or 3 in mind, so as Swift 4 continues to release, there very well may be new functionality in the language. But in case anyone is still using older Swift code, the other information presented will still be relevant. But I'll be keeping an eye on the new Swift 4.2 features.

Comment: I'm getting a `"Use of undeclared type 'MutableCollectionAlgorithms'"` error with Swift 4.2.