# swift 4 split array and filter

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, sections

i will build a UICollectionView with sections.
The sections are based on the return value from json.category.

the json format is like:

```
[{"id":"1",
  "name":"Apple",
  "category":"Fruits"},
{"id":"2",
 "name":"Pie",
 "category":"Fruits"},
{"id":"3",
 "name":"Tomato",
 "category":"Vegetable"}]
```

**I need a array filter hat the array is something like:** (for sectionsItems and sectionNames)

```
CategorieNames[STRING] = ["Fruits","Vegetable"] // the section names from json.category
Fruits = [STRING] = ["Apple","Pie"]
Vegetables = [STRING] = ["Tomato"]

Categories.append[Fruits]
Categories.append[Vegetables]

Categories[[STRING]] = [[Fruits],[Vegetable]]
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and add the actual JSON.

Comment: Swtift 4 Solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/55314505/7250862

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try bellow code.

```
        let arrData = [["id": "1",
                        "name": "Apple",
                        "category": "Fruit"],
                       ["id": "2",
                        "name": "Pie",
                        "category": "Fruit"],
                       ["id": "3",
                        "name": "Tomato",
                        "category": "Vegetable"]]

        let categorieNames = Array(Set(arrData.map({$0["category"]!})))
        var arrResult:[[String]] = []
        for i in 0..<categorieNames.count {

            let categories = arrData.filter({$0["category"] == categorieNames[i]}).map({$0["name"]!})
            arrResult.append(categories)
        }
        print("result : \(arrResult)")
```

> result : [["Apple", "Pie"], ["Tomato"]]

Comment: Thanks i‘ll test it

Comment: in playground it works like a charm! but I can't get it work with json data :-(

Answer (score 0):

you can do it as follows:

```
let arrData = [["id": "1",
                "name": "Apple",
                "category": "Fruit"],

               ["id": "2",
                "name": "Pie",
                "category": "Fruit"],

               ["id": "3",
                "name": "Tomato",
                "category": "Vegetable"]]



var categorys = [[String]]()
var fruits = [String]()
var vegetable = [String]()

for data in arrData {

     if let category = data["category"] {
          if category == "Fruit"{
               if let aFruit = data["name"] {
                    fruits.append(aFruit)
               }
          }
          else if category == "Vegetable" {
               if let aVeggeie = data["name"] {
                     vegetable.append(aVeggeie)
               }
          }


}
}
categorys.append(fruits)
categorys.append(vegetable)
```

Comment: hi, thanks, but the categories are unknown. I can't check =="Fruit"