# Use partition in Swift to move some predefined elements to the end of the Array

Tags: swift, dynamic-programming, partition

I would like to use the [`Array.partition(by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017524-partition) to move some **predefined** elements from an array to the the end of it.

Example:

```
var my_array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
let elementsToMove = [1, 3, 4, 5, 8]
// desired result: [0, 2, 6, 7, 9, ...remaining items in any order...]
```

Is there an elegant way to do that? Observe that `elementsToMove` does not follow a pattern.

Comment: Are all element from  `elementsToMove` known to be in `my_array`? Can there be duplicates? – `partition(by:)` is probably not suited because it does not preserve the order of the initial elements.

Comment: Note that `partition(by:)` is mutating, so `my_array` should probably be a `var`, not a `let` constant. Also, you might want to look at [In Swift, an efficient function that separates an array into 2 arrays based on a predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40010345/in-swift-an-efficient-function-that-separates-an-array-into-2-arrays-based-on-a).

Comment: @MartinR, the elements are known to be in `my_array` and there are no duplicates. @aalpmath, thank you for highlighting my `var / let` mistake :D.

Comment: There currently isn't a stable partitioning method in the stdlib, but there is a private one in test/Prototypes which may be useful for you – https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/345879429b5880e0e3f1e65d6414240b7894cd73/test/Prototypes/Algorithms.swift#L530

Answer (score 2):

`partition(by:)` does not preserve the order of the elements:

```
var my_array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
let elementsToMove = [1, 3, 4, 5, 8]

_ = my_array.partition(by: { elementsToMove.contains($0) } )
print(my_array) // [0, 9, 2, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 8, 1]
```

A simple solution would be to filter-out and append the elements from
the second array:

```
let my_array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
let elementsToMove = [1, 3, 4, 5, 8]

let newArray = my_array.filter({ !elementsToMove.contains($0) }) + elementsToMove
print(newArray) // [0, 2, 6, 7, 9, 1, 3, 4, 5, 8]
```

For larger arrays it can be advantageous to create a *set* of the
to-be-moved elements first:

```
let my_array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
let elementsToMove = [1, 3, 4, 5, 8]

let setToMove = Set(elementsToMove)
let newArray = my_array.filter({ !setToMove.contains($0) }) + elementsToMove
print(newArray) // [0, 2, 6, 7, 9, 1, 3, 4, 5, 8]
```

Comment: `A simple solution would be to filter-out and append the elements from the second array` — assuming author doesn't want to keep original count of elements moved elements of same kind.

Comment: @user28434: That's why I asked if there can be any duplicates (which OP answered in the negative).

Answer (score 0):

If you have unique object in your `my_array` then you can try something like this.

```
var my_array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
var tempArray = my_array //Preserve original array
let elementsToMove = [1, 3, 4, 5, 8]
let p = tempArray.partition(by: elementsToMove.contains)

//Now sort first part of tempArray on basis of your my_array to get order you want
let newArray = tempArray[0..<p].sorted(by: { my_array.index(of: $0)! < my_array.index(of: $1)! }) + tempArray[p...]
print(newArray)
```

**Output**

```
[0, 2, 6, 7, 9, 5, 4, 3, 8, 1]
```

Comment: No need to use a closure just pass the method as the parameter`tempArray.partition(by: elementsToMove.contains)`

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks for the suggestion, Edited the answer.