# Performance of moving zeros to the end of an array programming exercise

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm, performance

I wonder why my solution to this LeetCode "Move Zeros" problem is slower than the majority of other submissions. Is there a better way to approach this problem to make it faster?

The question is as follows:

> Given an array `nums`, write a function to move all 0's to the end of it while maintaining the relative order of the non-zero elements. You must do this in-place without making a copy of the array.
>
> Example:
>
> Input: [0,1,0,3,12]
>
> Output: [1,3,12,0,0]

This is my solution:

```
 func moveZeroes(_ nums: inout [Int]) {
    var index = 0
    for (i,n) in nums.enumerated()
    {
        if n != 0
        {
            nums[index] = n
            index += 1
        }
        
    }
    
    while index < nums.count
    {
        nums[index] = 0
        index += 1
    }
}
```

LeetCode gives me these statistics:

> Runtime: 52 ms, faster than **40.50%** of Swift online submissions for Move Zeroes.
> Memory Usage: 19.4 MB, less than 13.33% of Swift online submissions for Move Zeroes.

**EDIT 1:**

If I approach the problem as follows, it does not move the zeros at the end,

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

[image]

Comment: What about just `input.filter { $0 != 0 } + input.filter { $0 == 0 }`?

Comment: Please, define "it did not work". That has to work.

Comment: i have a similar answer with filter i guessed it was for you  also sort can be used but order will be gone

Comment: What you're looking for here is called a stable partitioning. https://stackoverflow.com/q/40010345/3141234

Comment: FYI, don't trust the numbers. I am pretty sure they don't even run optimized code and it seems most of the `40ms` second is actually the time for starting the performance test and the actual test is almost instant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is 36ms in-place solution for you :

```
class Solution {
    func moveZeroes(_ nums: inout [Int]) {

        if nums.count < 2 {
            return
        }

        var j = 0

        while j < nums.count, nums[j] != 0 {
            j += 1
        }

        if j < nums.count - 1 {
            for i in j+1..<nums.count {
                if nums[i] != 0 {
                    nums.swapAt(i, j)
                    j += 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: 36]

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about individual `ms`. There is probably a pretty big tolerance since the same solution submitted multiple times has different results (+10ms in my testing). Unfortunately, most of the memory usage is probably the Swift runtime therefore small differences are also unreliable.

Comment: Actually, it seems that it takes about `40ms` for the performance test to start and the actual test is almost instantaneous. What a bad performance test! I would say it's not even optimized.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see, it's likely other submissions are doing this

- Check and count 0's in string
- Remove 0's
- Replace number of 0's at the end of the string

A logical method no doubt, but I'd say yours just picks the basic needs of the challenge and goes for it.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally use:

```
input = input.filter { $0 != 0 } + input.filter { $0 == 0 }
```

[image]

which can be simplified to one pass:

```
let nonZeros = input.filter { $0 != 0 }
input = nonZeros + Array(repeating: 0, count: input.count - nonZeros.count)
```

[image]

EDIT: The simplest version without creating a new array would be some primitive version of bubble sort, e.g.:

```
var numZeros = 0

// iterate array from start to end
for (offset, element) in input.enumerated() {
    if element == 0 {
        // count every zero
        numZeros += 1
    } else if numZeros > 0 {
        // move every non-zero element left
        input[offset - numZeros] = element    
        // replace with zero
        input[offset] = 0
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention in the question that You must do this `in-place` without making a copy of the array.

Comment: @hotspring That means you have to use some kind of bubble sort I guess.

Comment: @hotspring the duplicate same and was for you also

Comment: @Sh_Khan, please check my edit referring to screenshot.

Comment: @Sulthan, could you please check my edit referring to screnshot at the bottom.

Comment: @hotspring Okey, added an  in-place solution.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4.2 or later using `removeAll` mutating method:

Mutating the input:

```
class Solution {
    func moveZeroes(_ nums: inout [Int]) {
        var counter = 0
        nums.removeAll {
            if $0 == 0 {
                counter += 1
                return true
            }
            return false
        }
        nums += repeatElement(0, count: counter)
    }
}
```

---

A similar approach for Swift 4.1 or earlier

```
func moveZeroes(_ nums: inout [Int]) {
    var counter = 0
    nums.indices.reversed().forEach {
        if nums[$0] == 0 {
            counter += 1
            nums.remove(at: $0)
        }
    }
    nums += repeatElement(0, count: counter)
}
```

---

```
var input = [0,1,0,3,12]
moveZeroes(&input)
input   // [1, 3, 12, 0, 0]
```

---

Non mutating approach:

```
func moveZeroes(_ nums: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    var counter = 0
    return nums.filter {
        if $0 == 0 { counter += 1 }
        return $0 != 0
    } + repeatElement(0, count: counter)
}
```

---

```
let  input = [0,1,0,3,12]

let zerosMoved = moveZeroes(input)
zerosMoved   // [1, 3, 12, 0, 0]
```

Comment: It is really nice approach but cannot handle one scenario which I attached into the my question as `EDIT 2`

Comment: pretty sure you would have to iterate from the end. However, removing elements from the middle of the array is probably worse than a simple `filter`.

Comment: @Sulthan yes if I were not appending the removed element to the end of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is the half-stable-partition algorithm. The benefit is the items are swapped rather than removed and inserted/appended.

*Half-stable* means the order of the left side of the split point is preserved.

```
extension Array {

    mutating func halfStablePartition(indexes : IndexSet) { // code is O(n)
        guard var i = indexes.first, i < count else { return }
        var j = index(after: i)
        var k = indexes.integerGreaterThan(i) ?? endIndex
        while j != endIndex {
            if k != j { swapAt(i, j); formIndex(after: &i) }
            else { k = indexes.integerGreaterThan(k) ?? endIndex }
            formIndex(after: &j)
        }
    }
}

var input = [0,1,0,3,12]

let indices = IndexSet(input.indices.filter{input[$0] == 0})
input.halfStablePartition(indexes: indices)
```

Answer (score 1):

For modifying array in place, and keeping it:

**O(n)** for Time Complexity

**O(1)** for Space Complexity

Cracked my head way to long for this one. The cleanest way if you swap element that is NOT zero:

```
func moveZeroes(_ nums: inout [Int]) {
    // amount of swaps, will be used a as reference for next swap index
    var j = 0 
    
    for (i, e) in nums.enumerated() {
        if e != 0 {
            nums.swapAt(j, i)
            j += 1
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One fast solution is to shift non-zero elements to the left by the amount of zeros encountered until then:

```
func moveZeroes(_ nums: inout [Int]) {
    var offset = 0
    for i in 0..<nums.count {
        if nums[i] == 0 { offset += 1 }
        else { nums.swapAt(i, i-offset) }
    }
}
```

This solution takes exactly N steps, and at each step we either perform an addition, or a swap, which are both quite fast.

Your solution, on the other hand required two iterations, resulting in 2*N steps, which is why it was slower than other solutions.

Comment: `nums.indices.forEach { nums[$0] == 0 ? offset += 1 : nums.swapAt($0, $0 - offset) }`

Comment: I have used exactly the same solution, with a manual assign instead of `swapAt`. To be honest, Actually, I have done some performance testing and all the solutions have almost the same performance. Of course, you can improve slightly using microoptimizations (removing function calls) but you need an array with 10M elements to really see a meaningful difference (0.02 sec in my testing)

Comment: @Sulthan I think the numbers are similar because all answers are O(N). Some of the solutions use more than N steps due to implementation details, however as you said the time difference is not noticeable for small to medium arrays.