# Swift: Most efficient way to split array of objects into multiple arrays based on object property?

Tags: arrays, swift

What's the most efficient way to split an array of objects into multiple arrays based on a property?

For example, say we have the following items:

```swift
var items = [
    Food(name: "Cupcake", foodType: .dessert),
    Food(name: "Banana", foodType: .fruit),
    Food(name: "Grandma's Soup", foodType: .custom("home-made"),
    Food(name: "Ice-cream", foodType: .dessert),
]
```

What's the best way to split it into the following arrays based on `foodType`:

```swift
[Food(name: "Cupcake", foodType: .dessert), Food(name: "Ice-cream", foodType: .dessert)]
[Food(name: "Banana", foodType: .fruit)],
[Food(name: "Grandma's Soup", foodType: .custom("home-made")]
```

In my example, foodType is an enum that looks like this:

```swift
enum FoodType {
    case dessert
    case fruit
    case custom(string)
    case vegetable
}
```

Normally I'd make my enum conform to `CaseIterable` and then loop over `allCases`, however, given that I'm using associated values, that's not possible.

##### My Approach:

```swift
var sections: [FoodType: [String]] = [:]
items.forEach {
    sections[$0.foodType] = (sections[$0.foodType] ?? []) + [$0.name]
}
```

Comment: If there is `.custom("foo")` and `.custom("bar")`, do you want them to be in the same group or different groups?

Comment: Good question! Different groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order of the groups doesn't matter, I would make `FoodType` conform to `Hashable`:

```
enum FoodType: Hashable {
    case dessert
    case fruit
    case custom(String)
    case vegetable
}
```

Then use the `Dictionary.init(grouping:by:)` initialiser to create a `[FoodType:[Food]]`:

```
Dictionary(grouping: items, by: \.foodType)
```

The `values` of this dictionary are the groups you want:

```
let groups = [_](Dictionary(grouping: items, by: \.foodType).values)
```

This preserves the order of the elements in each group, but the order of the groups themselves is not preserved.

If you want to preserve the order of the groups, you can do:

```
let groups = items.reduce(into: [[Food]]()) { acc, food in
    for i in acc.indices {
        if acc[i][0].foodType == food.foodType {
            acc[i].append(food)
            return
        }
    }
    acc.append([food])
}
```

Comment: If order does matter, `reduce(into:)` solves it; might want to show that too.

Comment: Oh wow this is so much cleaner than what I was thinking (I added my approach above). Also thank you for adding a way to have it ordered if needed. I imagine it's the same in speed, however I'll take the cleaner approach.

Comment: @matt You mean handwriting something similar to `Dictionary.init(grouping:by:)`?

Comment: Yes, just dealing into piles.

Comment: https://github.com/apple/swift-collections/blob/main/Documentation/OrderedDictionary.md

Comment: Why do you think this question is not a duplicate? You even gave the same solution as the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61238966/1974224) to that question. Two questions that have the same solution are duplicates, even if the questions are not formulated identically.

Comment: @Cristik I think an additional problem that the OP of this question is having, which the duplicate does not address, and hence cannot be solved solely by the duplicate, is that the grouping key is an enum with associated values, which needs to conform to `Hashable` first.

Comment: Well, that wouldn't have been almost trivial to fix, as the compiler would've given a clear error regarding the `Hashable` conformance.